# Array and EnterFrame eventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem that I hope you can help me resolve. I made that code:

```
var dates_array:Array =[y1,y2,y3];
var i= 1;

for each(var dates_sym:MovieClip in dates_array){
    dates_sym.visible=false;
};

france_map.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fnCheckDate);
function fnCheckDate (evt:Event):void{
var i = france_map.currentFrame;
}

function fnDateSym (evt:Event):void{
dates_array[i].visible=true;
}
```

It is supposed to make a symbol (y1, y2 or y3 (there are more symbols, but didn't put them in the code for clarity) appear depending on what frame the main symbol is. When I compil, it shows no errors, but when I try it in my app, nothing happens. 
I'm still a beginner, and I really don't see what's wrong. 
If you need more context I can give it. Thanks in advance. 
Jeryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fnCheckDate` function is called on enter frame, but that function never does anything except setting `i`. The other function - `fnDateSym` -  sets the `visible` property based on the value of `i`. Which is what you want - but `fnDateSym` is never called anywhere in your posted code.

That may just be because you've left out some code. I'm guessing you might be calling `fnDateSym` from elsewhere and expect it to use the global `i`, as set by `fnCheckDate`. And yes, it *will* use the global `i`. But `fnCheckDate` doesn't *set* the global `i`:

```
var i = france_map.currentFrame;
```

The `var` keyword declares a variable within the current scope. A function creates a new scope. In other words, you're declaring a variable `i` local to your function and assigning the `currentFrame` value to that - rather than to the already existing variable `i` in the global scope (`var i = 1`). When your function exits, the local `i` is "lost" - and the global `i` hasn't changed - it will still be 1.

So the quick fix is to simply change it to:

```
i = france_map.currentFrame;
```

Now you're not declaring a new variable, but rather setting the value of your global `i` variable.

**ETA**: A bit of "teaching you how to fish rather than giving you a fish"... An easy way to debug these kinds of issues is to check the value of your variables using the `trace` function. For example:

```
function fnDateSym (evt:Event):void
{
    trace("i is:", i);
    dates_array[i].visible=true;
}
```

Now, if you don't see any traces in the output window that means your function isn't called at all. If you constantly see "i is: 1" then you know that `i` doesn't change and that this is the root of the problem. You could just use trace(i) - I just tend to add some kind of text to the trace - makes it easier to tell what each line in the output is, when you have more traces.

Unrelated, just a bit of code review...

Note that `ENTER_FRAME` is triggered *on every frame refresh*. I.e., it doesn't mean "when I enter a new frame on the timeline". It simply means, "when a frame is drawn in the player". In other words, it's called 24 times per second - or whatever frame rate you've chosen in Flash - no matter if `currentFrame` doesn't change (e.g. because you've called `france_map.stop()`).

This may be fine in your case - after all, setting `visible` to `true` 24 times per second doesn't actually cause any side effects. If you're doing more than that, however, it may be wasteful - or it may cause unexpected issues, since it's called more often than you really want.

One way to make something similar to a "enter **timeline** frame" event would be:

```
var previousFrame:int; // used for storing the last currentFrame we encountered

mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameListener);

function enterFrameListener(event:Event):void
{
    // Are we on a different frame than last time?
    if (previousFrame != mc.currentFrame)
    {
       currentFrameChanged();
       previousFrame = mc.currentFrame;
    }
}

function currentFrameChanged()
{
   // Do stuff that should be done when the current frame changes
   // - rather than on every frame refresh.
}
```

It's hard to tell exactly how you're doing things (again, because it seems a call to `fnDateSym` is left out) - but depending on how `fnDateSym` is called, mostly you wouldn't need `fnCheckDate` at all. Just do:

```
dates_array[france_map.currentFrame] = true;
```

Other than that, just for "niceness", you may want to declare the type for `i`:

```
var i:int = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I changed the var i to i and it worked. But, i did i you suggested and replaced the function fnCheckDate with date_array[france_map.currentFrame]! I didn't know about EnterFrame, so i'm really glad you took the time to explain and give an alternative. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, and yeah, I had a call to fnDateSym higher in the code, but I forgot to copy/paste it :)